# Didn't find class "android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout"

Tags: android-studio-3.0

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
//androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-beta01'
//androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-beta01'

implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0-beta01'
```

I am trying to use androidx libraries. although i have added "
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'" i am getting this error.

Comment: solved! the problem was in my .xml file i was using the support library instead of androidx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your xml and see if you are using `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout` .

Answer (score 0):

Just check the .xml file. If you are using `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` replace that with `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout`